# In GitHub wiki, absolute links to Markdown leads to raw.githubusercontent

Tags: github, markdown, wiki

Here is my problem:
I want to write a GitHub wiki where hypertext links to other pages are absolute paths (I have sub-folders and so on. In my case it would be easier this way).

That is, `\[label](https://github.com/repo/../fileName.md)`.

When I click to the link, it leads to the right page, but without any interpretation of the Markdown format. How can I write this link so that it will lead to an interpreted page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got my answer:

We don't need any path to the file if we want it to be interpreted as a Markdown file. Just write the name and GitHub wiki will do the rest. Once you write a path (relative or absolute), GitHub will interpret it as a raw.githubusercontent.

Comment: Good that you have found the answer to your problem :) but just so that people can see that this question has been answered please mark your comment as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

When linking to another page in your GitHub wiki with a path located below `https://github.com/<org>/<repo>/wiki/...` you must omit any extra path info, as well as the `.md` extension and use just the filename.

GitHub will serve the raw text if you include the `.md` extension. If you leave off the extension then the file will be rendered as HTML.

This behaviour applies only when linking to another *page*.  When linking to an *image*, the behaviour is different; you must include any extra path info and/or file extensions.

e.g. `[API Reference](API-Reference)` is equivalent to `https://github.com/<org>/<repo>/wiki/API-Reference` and could link to a page described in the file at `https://github.com/<org>/<repo>/wiki/api/API-Reference.md` - although the latter link will return the raw file content.

The behaviour is different again, if you link to a page outside of the current GitHub wiki. e.g. the README.md file in the repo itself will render as html even with the `.md` extension. (In fact, I doubt the link would work if you left off the extension.) The reason for this is that it is a wiki feature that allows you to address a file without the extension; the wiki has no way to affect the rendering behaviour of external web pages.